# ggplot: geom_text should not appear in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following ggplot image. Can someone please tell me how I can get rid of the "a" showing up in the legend? I've already tried to put "label = n" outside of the aes(), but it doesnt work. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Try with `geom_text(..., show.legend = FALSE)`

Comment: thanks! That works fine

Answer (score 3):

`geom_text(..., show.legend = FALSE)` works fine, thanks!